# Skipping a entire directory using Helicon ISAPI rewrite v3.0

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-6, isapi-rewrite

Here is my current .htaccess file.  This file is in my root directory for my site.
I want to add a rule that in plain english will do the following.

> COMPLETELY SHUT OFF RULES PROCESSING FOR
>   http://www.sc-pa.com/dr405/****.****

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net|sc-pa.net|sarasotaproperty.net) [nc]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sc-pa.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*)/eurl\.axd/[0-9a-f]+ /$1 [L]

RewriteMap  lc int:tolower

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*(js|css|inc|jpg|gif|png)
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*(web_content/pdf/|/dr405/).*
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!.*/web_content/pdf/)([^/]*?\.pdf) /web_content/pdf/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule pasite-(.*\.asp)$  /content/$1 [R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule home\.asp$  / [R=301]

#RewriteRule ^search/tpp/?$ content/search_tangible.asp 
#RewriteRule ^search/?$ content/search_real_property.asp 
#RewriteRule ^downloads/?$ content/downloads.asp
#RewriteRule ^(.*?view)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)? /search/parcel_detail.asp?account=0&$2=$3 [NC,LP,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the site to IIS7 and used the built in rewrite module.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to completely disable rewriting and .htaccess files for this directory and subdirectories you may use  section in the HTTPD.CONF file. Here is an example:

```
<Directory C:/inetpub/mysite/dr405>
   RewriteEngine off
   AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Please note you need to use fully qualified path, i.e. C:/intepub...

If you simply want to exclude this directory so rules from current .htaccess file will not be applied you may place this rule at the beginning of your site's .htaccess file:

```
  RewriteBase /


  RewriteRule ^dr405 - [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.sarasotaproperty.net|www.sc-pa.net|sc-pa.net|sarasotaproperty.net) [nc]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sc-pa.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA]
  RewriteRule (.*)/eurl\.axd/[0-9a-f]+ /$1 [L]
  # ... etc....
```

Comment: This is an old question.  But I'm actually working on this again.  THis solution doesn't seem to work.  My rewrite.log file shows all the rules still being applied, if I use the Directory directive approach.  (Which I prefer)